# presale options for polygon

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, contract-deployment

I've seen a few different options but was having a hard time figuring out which would be best. I was thinking of using because it seems the most straight forward, but since I'm a novice I was looking for some feedback from people with more knowledge than me.

```
    address payable public owner;
  
uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether; 
uint256 public min_contribution = 0.1 ether; 

function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public payable returns (bool success) {
    require(msg.value >= min_contribution);
    require(msg.value <= max_contribution);
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi matt.m37? Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! What's the question exactly?

Comment: I was planning on using this code for my presale contract but I was wondering if there was a better option?

Comment: The code is just a simple ERC-20 transfer function. Before doing a presale I'd recommend to learn a bit more about contracts and solidity. There are plenty of tutorials on YT, Edx, Udemy, etc.